# NuxtとReactには、Vue CLI 3のような、便利な雛形作成ウィザード 兼 ビルドボタンを含むGUIは存在しますか？

Tags: vue.js, reactjs, nuxt.js

私はこれまで Vue CLI 3で複数のプロダクトを作りました。

しかし、Nuxtを使ったプロジェクトを新規作成したことはありません。

Reactについても、シェアが高いので興味があります。
しかし、やはりプロジェクトを新規作成したことはありません。

その理由としては、私はVue CLI 3の便利さに慣れており、

- 便利な雛形作成ウィザード
- ビルドボタンを含むGUI

が存在する環境に、慣れてしまったためです。

ファイル名の付け方、ファイルの配置について自由度が高すぎると、
ベストなものが決まるまで迷ってしまい、高速な開発ができません。

私がNuxtとReactに期待しているのは、

```sh
$ vue create my-project
$ vue ui
```

の2つです。

現在のNuxtとReactには、それらの機能は存在しますか？

もし存在しない場合、
ファイル名の付け方、ファイルの配置について自由度が高いことを、
他の方々はどんな方法で解決していますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

雛形作成ツールに関しては以下のものが対応するでしょう。

- nuxt: `create-nuxt-app` - https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app
- react: `create-react-app` - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

> ファイル名の付け方、ファイルの配置について自由度が高いことを、他の方々はどんな方法で解決していますか？

以前にも似たような質問がありましたので、こちらを案内いたします。

[Nuxt.jsのstore配下のディレクトリ構成について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66916)

自由度が高い状態は開発がスケールしづらい状態なので、いくつかの視点でファイル/ディレクトリのアーキテクチャを評価します。

- スケールしやすい命名、構造か
- 依存関係がわかりやすい構造か
- 誰が書いても似たような状態に落ち着くか
- 上記がわかりやすい状態か（ドキュメントがかける状態か）

他にも評価基準があるかと思いますが、一旦この辺で。

さて、`わかりやすい`をどう表現するかは難しい問題ですが、ある程度は既存のやり方を踏襲することで達成できます。MVC（Model/View/Controller）や、クリーンアーキテクチャなどの広く一般的に知られたアーキテクチャにドメインがそれぞれの役割の場所に収まり、役割のブレがない状態を目指すことです。

すでにあるパターンを利用することで「命名」の大半はすでにあるアーキテクチャから利用するわけなので、これに属するコードの役割が決定できます。実際に書くコードはそれぞれのプロジェクトのコンポーネントや処理の名前になります。

具体的な例が無いじゃないか、と思いますが、命名についてどうするか、と疑問を持ち始めたら抽象的な話は避けられなくなるので、本回答や[リンク先](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66916)を読んでわからなかった用語を調べてみると視野が広がると思います。